# javascript update all values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to add a new property "comment" to all the students and return the ClassFoo?

```
ClassFoo = {
    "Total": 3, 
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "Peter",
            "grade": "C"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ben",
            "grade": "B"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ann",
            "grade": "B"
        },
    ]
};

Comments(B) = {
    "grade": "B",
    "comment": "Good"
};

Comments(C) = {
    "grade": "C",
    "comment": "Work harder"
};
```

Become like this

```
ClassFoo = {
    "Total": 3, 
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "Peter",
            "grade": "C",
            "comment": "Work harder"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ben",
            "grade": "B",
            "comment": "Good"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ann",
            "grade": "B",
            "comment": "Good"
        },
    ]
};
```

Should I create a new object?
use .map for ClassFoo.students? 
and then match comments if Comments.grade === ClassFoo.students.grade, then .push comment?

Comment: so loop over it and add it...

Comment: Your syntax is not valid on line 2. Looks like `ClassFoo` it should be an `{}` object instead of an `[]` array.

Comment: do you want to get a new object or the same with mutated properties? why does `Comments` contain `grade`?

Comment: 'Commonts.grade' is to check the grade of each student

Answer (score 3):

```js
class ClassFoo {
  constructor(students) {
    this.total = students.length
    this.students = students
    this.students.forEach(student => {
      if (this.Comments[student.grade]) {
        student.comment = this.Comments[student.grade]
      }
    });
  }
  
  get Comments() {
    return {
      B: 'Good',
      C: 'Work Harder',
    }
  }
}

const classFoo = new ClassFoo([
  {
    "name": "Peter",
    "grade": "C"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ben",
    "grade": "B"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ann",
    "grade": "A"
  },
]);

console.log(classFoo)
```

Comment: What if I don't know what are the comments for different grade yet?

Comment: Well an E or an F in this example would result in an `undefined` comment, which is relatively representative of the grade if it doesn't have a comment yet. If you would prefer to leave out the comment if it is undefined, that can be done.

Comment: Can it do `Comments.grade === ClassFoo.students.grade` ?

Comment: I don't want to list out all the comments for grades

Comment: In that case, simply check `if (this.Comments[student.grade])` is a truthy value before adding it to the student – I've updated that answer.

Comment: What should the result be if Ann has an A and not a B? Should she be excluded from the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for..of` loop like this

```js
ClassFoo = {
  "Total": 3,
  "students": [{
      "name": "Peter",
      "grade": "C"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ben",
      "grade": "B"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ann",
      "grade": "B"
    },
  ]
};

for (let student of ClassFoo.students) {

  if (student.grade === 'B') {
    student.comment = 'good';
  } else if (student.grade === 'C') {
    student.comment = 'work harder';
  }

}

console.log(ClassFoo)
```

A `for..of` loop will iterate over every element in the students array and add a property comment with the value of 'good' on a student object.

Comment: what if I don't know what are the comment for grade? and students have different grades?

Comment: Updated the answer, you can just put an if statement in your for of loop and in this way dynamically add comments based on the grade.

Comment: if I have 24 grades, it is bad to list out all the conditions